# how to change the selected value of a disabled dropdownlist in jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, disabled-control

I want to change the selected value to a disabled dropdownlist to someother value on a button click. Managed to change the value but the issue is when i submit the form previously selected value is submitted.

```
$("#RatesImplementation").click(function () {
    $('#DrpDwnRequestStatus').val('Rates Implementation').trigger('change');
    $('#DrpDwnNextStage').val('Implementation Approval').trigger('change');
    
});
```

this wont set selected attribute for the option.
Any help would be appreciated.Thanks!

---

I was hidden variable for submitting the disabled field value.

```
$("#RatesImplementation").click(function () {
    $('#DrpDwnRequestStatus').val('Rates Implementation').trigger('change');
    $('#DrpDwnNextStage').val('Implementation Approval ').trigger('change');
    $('#hdnRequestStatus').val('Rates Implementation');
    $('#hdnNextStage').val('Implementation Approval ')
});
```

Comment: `disabled` elements are [not submitted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled).  If it's getting the "previously selected value" it's getting it from somewhere else.   You'll need to provide details on how that works.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the hint. Issue has been resolved.